# Truncated text in resized gnuplot LaTeX output

Tags: gnuplot

I have a recurring issue when generating latex documents from gnuplot as soon as I specify a `set size n,m` where n or m is greater than one.

Here are the minimal codes producing the issue:

#### Gnuplot instructions

```
set terminal latex
set output "plot.tex"
set size 1,2
set title "Graph Title"
set xlabel "$x$ axis"
set ylabel "$y$ axis"
plot sin(x)
```

#### (very minimal) LaTeX document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\input{plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I then run `gnuplot plot.gp` followed by either `xelatex document.tex` or `pdflatex document.tex` or `latex document.pdf`, since any of them will produce the issue.

The result is that no **text** displays outside of the default size zone. As you can see, both axis labels and numbering stops at the half of the *y* axis, as well as no title at top of the graph:

[image: No text displays screenshot]

Can anyone reproduce this issue on his computer, or is there an issue with my LaTeX/gnuplot installation ? I would be glad if anyone could provide with a solution for this issue.

Comment: Just use the `epslatex` terminal instead of the `latex` one.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks!

(Assuming I use `graphicx` package in LaTeX.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem with gnuplot version 4.6.3. The `plot.tex` file doesn't even contain all the missing labels (e.g. `$y$ axis`). That seems to be a bug in the `latex` terminal.

For using LaTeX strings, use the `epslatex`, `cairolatex`, `context` or `lua tikz` terminal which are known to work fine.